# Write-output when executing script in a wpf event script

Tags: powershell

I have a script that accepts lots of parameters and is fairly big. I've been asked to build a GUI for executing the script, so users can easily execute the script without making mistakes. So the idea was that the GUI script collects all the parameters, and then executes the script.

The "main" script uses `write-output` and `start-transcript` for logging to the shell and to a file. This also works.
But when I execute the script from the GUI script I'm not getting every output to the shell or to the log. I figured that this is because of `write-output` because `Write-Host` does work, but everywhere I go I hear people say that you shouldn't use `write-host` (for instance: https://youtu.be/SSJot1ycM70?t=24m1s).
So how do I get this to work?

Currently I use this to execute the script from the gui:

```
& $PSscriptroot\guitest2.ps1 -switchparam1:$localvar1 -switchparam2:$localvar2 -stringparam $localvar3
```

I have tried to run a new instance of powershell via cmd, but I don't seem to get this to work. I have also no idea how to "send" the parameters to the script this way.

```
Invoke-Expression 'cmd /c powershell.exe -file C:\...\script.ps1 -paramters.
```

or

```
Invoke-Expression 'cmd /c powershell.exe -command {C:\..\script.ps1 -paramters..}
```

The two scripts below do exactly what I want. But when I execute the script in a wpf event (ie after the start button has been pressed) the second script only shows the `write-warning`, `write-error` and `write-host` output, so not the `write-output`.

script1:

```
#gui script

$boolean = $true
$string = "test"

& $PSscriptroot\script2.ps1 -switch:$boolean -string $string
```

script2:

```
param(
    [switch]$switch,
    [string]$string
    )

Start-Transcript 

write-output "output"
write-host "host"
$a = "Variable"
$a

write-error "error"
Write-Warning "warning"
Write-Debug "debug"

Stop-Transcript
```

EDIT:
did some more testing. Apparently `write-output` completely doesn't work when called in a `wpf` event. For example:

```
$wpf.startButton.Add_Click({
    write-output "This message is not shown"
})
```

Not sure if this is a bug or not

Comment: Can you get this down to an [mcve]? Kinda hard to debug code we can't see. How does the script output its results? `Write-Output` can be used behind the scenes even if you are not writing out the cmdlet.

Comment: You're right. I have added two example scripts that **do** work. But when I run the last line of script 1 in a wpf event (after the start button has been pressed) I'm not getting all the outputs back to my shell/log

Answer (score 0):

`Write-Output` passes an object through the pipeline to another command. Essentially the statement

```
Write-Output <expression>
```

is in many cases exactly identical to

```
<expression>
```

Other `Write-*` cmdlets behave a bit differently. In your case you have an event handler, which has no return value anyway. Your example is the same as

```
"This message is not shown"
```

or even

```
return "This message is not shown"
```

As the string is part of the return value of that script block, which no one ever looks at.

If you want output in the host application, use `Write-Host`. That's what it's for. `Write-Output` is something you rarely, if ever, need in a script.